# Why showing 1 error in this css

Tags: css

why showing 1 error on my css code
My CSS code:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 991px)
.mobile_header.top_nav_mobile .main_menu_nav > li > a {
padding: 11px 36px 11px 44px;
display: block;
font-size: 20px;
color: #ffffff;
text-transform: none !important;
font-weight: 700;
letter-spacing: -0.04em;
}
```

Comment: I don't know why people are upvoting this when the only error is that its missing braces.

Comment: you got missing curly brackets here -> `@media only screen and (max-width: 991px)   {   #selector{  }    }`

Answer (score 2):

The styles that apply to a certain [`@media` query](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp) must be enclosed in braces.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 991px) {
    .mobile_header.top_nav_mobile .main_menu_nav > li > a {
        padding: 11px 36px 11px 44px;
        display: block;
        font-size: 20px;
        color: #ffffff;
        text-transform: none !important;
        font-weight: 700;
        letter-spacing: -0.04em;
    }
}
```

If you want to apply a media query to an entire CSS file, include it in your HTML `<head>` like this.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-width: 991px)" href="mobile_style.css">
```

See more examples [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp).